# getting Error pymysql.err.InternalError: Packet sequence number wrong - got 102 expected 14 while selecting table name in database

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, flask, pymysql

I am building web application. in front end it shows the tables list available in database for selecting data. for first table it is not throwing any error but when i select another table it is throwing this error

> pymysql.err.InternalError: Packet sequence number wrong - got 102 expected 14

I don't know what is the reason for this. here is the flask code

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL(app)
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = '****'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = '****'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'vehicledata1'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
tables = [table[0] for table in cursor.fetchall()]
print(tables)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    selected_table = request.args.get("table_name", tables[0])
    print(selected_table)
    query = f"SELECT * FROM {selected_table}"
    cursor.execute(query)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[col[0] for col in cursor.description]) if data else None
    print(df)
    return render_template("index.html", tables=tables, df=df, selected_table=selected_table)
@app.route("/range", methods=["POST"])
def data_range():
    start = request.form.get("start")
    end = request.form.get("end")
    selected_table = request.form.get("table_name")

    query = f"SELECT * FROM {selected_table} WHERE date_time BETWEEN '{start}' AND '{end}'"
    cursor.execute(query)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[col[0] for col in cursor.description]) if data else None
    average_odo = None
    if df is not None:
     print(df)
     average_odo = df['Odometer']
     print(average_odo)
     return jsonify({
        'htmlresponse': f"Average Odometer: {average_odo}"
     })
```

```html
    <h1>Table Viewer</h1>

    <form action="/" method="GET">
        <label>Select a table:</label><br>
        {% for table in tables %}
        <input type="radio" name="table_name" value="{{ table }}" id="{{ table }}" {% if table == selected_table %}checked{% endif %}>
        <label for="{{ table }}">{{ table }}</label><br>
        {% endfor %}
        <br>

        <label>Select a date range:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="reportrange" name="daterange" readonly style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc;" placeholder="Select a date range">
        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```